# SSAS cube login specific security on data

Tags: security, authentication, ssas, cube

I've encountered the following problem - I already have a working cube that processes lots of data on a schedule. The requirement I got now was to restrict the data in the cube according to specific logins. I'm aware of dynamic SSAS cube security through roles or even logins but I don't see them helping me as I have a kind of a hybrid scenario, and it is as follows:

For example, imagine you have a cube processing sales and income of an international trading company, and you belonged to a role of *country directors*; what I want to do is adjust permissions so that every *country director* sees all the measures and dimensions, but they see sales/income only from their country.

Is this possible?

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I might not have made the best example above. My scenario is slightly different, in a way that there isn't a business rule that would place any two users in a same group. Basically, every user has to see only data that somehow refers to him/her. And this really can't be done manually as there's over 4000 users...

Best regards,

*MK_*

Comment: Ok, I see. If it's SSAS Tabular follow the link I've posted. They use a lookup User Security table and filter it with this formula `'Sales Territory'[Sales Territory Id]=LOOKUPVALUE('Employee Security'[Sales Territory Id], 'Employee Security'[Login Id], USERNAME(), 'Employee Security'[Sales Territory Id], 'Sales Territory'[Sales Territory Id])`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both Tabular and Multidimensional SSAS have row filtering options. In your scenario you need:

1. A Country dimension
2. Create a role for each Country that has directors
3. Assign each director to their specific role
4. Row filter each role by their correspondant Country dimension

Comment: So basically someone has to assign every single person to a role manually in order for this to work?
Can it be done by loading people's roles from the database?

Comment: @MK_ - I found the following link to do it dynamically, but I haven't tested https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479759(v=sql.120).aspx.
On our installation we have roles on AD grouping users from the same location.

Comment: I might not have proposed a good example that has 1-1 relationship to my actual problem. I'm editing the question with further details.